# Difference between stdin and calling arguments?

Tags: c

If I had a method

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
```

I am under the impression that calling arguments and receiving data through standard input are somewhat the same things. What is the difference between adding the arguments "1 2 3 4" and receiving standard input "5 6 7 8"? and when would you pick one method over the other?

Comment: the difference is the sum produced. (`10` and `26`):-)

Comment: don't get offended !! Joskes apart, you really need to be more specific about your question. There are lot of aspects. What you want to know in particular?

Comment: Adding arguments `"1 2 3 4"` makes `argc` 5 and `argv` holds the name of the program and the 4 arguments which you gave it. The standard input or `stdin` is not related to this. Functions like `scanf` scan input from the `stdin` ,not the command line. Your question is a bit unclear to me too.... Please add more details. OK; Now your question looks alright.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'm curious to when you would use either one as right now I'm under the impression that these two are used to call something INTO a program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in how you access them.

Arguments are accessible through `argv`. Standard input is accessible through the `stdin` file descriptor.

case 1 - command line arguments:

```
int i;
for (i=1; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("%s", argv[i]);      // Prints "1 2 3 4"
}
```

case 2 - standard input:

```
char buffer[121];
while (scanf("%120s", buffer) == 1) {
    printf("%s", buffer);      // Prints "5 6 7 8"
}
```

Comment: Just to add to this, later case, we can use formatted IO. but IMO, this is really too broad a question to be answered here.

Comment: I increased the buffer by one, should be fine now.